# How to make sanity io array select as multiselect?

Tags: content-management-system, sanity, headless-cms

I have a lot of tags, and I need to select a lot for each document. It is uncomfortable to click one by one every time. Also I see selected elements. How can I remake it into somefield like a multiselect? It could be even native. Or how to select all tags at once?

I am using array:

```js
{
  title: 'Language',
  name: 'language',
  type: 'array',
  options: {
    layout: 'grid'
  },
  of: [{
    type: 'reference',
    title: 'Lang',
    to: {
      type: 'settingLanguages'
    }
  }],
},
```

[image]

Comment: It would be really cool if you could check the correct answers as "answered" even if it the answers boil down to "sorry, there's no easy way to do that" :)

Comment: @thomax it is an important point.! I am going to answer in the coming days.

Comment: ^I've the same issue, do you have an answer?

Comment: @Paolo Unfortunately, no. If you find a solution, please share it. We need to extend their react component for that.

Comment: @Paolo you can try ask a question in a https://sanity-io-land.slack.com/ it's the only one I've been using lately

Answer (score 9):

Dropdown example (Add field to schema):

```
{
  title: 'Genre',
  name: 'genre',
  type: 'string',
  options: {
    list: [
      { title: 'Sci-Fi', value: 'sci-fi' },
      { title: 'Western', value: 'western' },
    ],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible out of the box with the default array component, but you should be able to create an input like this by building a custom input for it with the behaviour you want.

More on how to build custom inputs: https://www.sanity.io/docs/extending/custom-input-widgets